# CodeBehind attribute not working with my webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webserver

I am making my C# ASP.NET webApplication in Visual Studio 2013.
When I use CodeBehind @Page attribute, It's raising an error:

> "Couldn't load type 'MyApplication.MasterPage'" .

Using CodeFile fixes this problem. 
But, I don't want to copy my C# source files to website. How can I resolve this Issue. My Webserver is hosted with GoDaddy.

Comment: do you have the master page? maybe you have removed

Comment: No. I have master page and a child page only. 
If I use CodeFile in master page, the child page will raise problem. If I use codeFile in both pages. Everything fine, but I need to copy .cs files.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your application on **RELEASE** mode and just publish the aspx files and the binary.
Those files will be part of the output of the build process.

Comment: Yes, I did the same But.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer.
In GoDaddy control panel, there's an option to convert directory to Application.
CodeBehind will only work as Application. I created a virtual folder, and converted it to Application. Everything works fine now.